# JSONKit: changing and serializing JSON attribute's value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, jsonkit

I am using JSONKit to parse JSON string into NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

My question is: how can I change the dictionary values and get a changed JSON String?

I've tried to change the dictionary values:

```
[deserializedData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iRatings] forKey:@"ratings"];
```

But the app crashes in that line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the other answers are correct, what you *really want* in this case is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonString mutableObjectFromJSONString];
```

The `mutableObjectFromJSONString` method will create a mutable dictionary directly, which saves time and memory.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDictionary` is an immutable dictionary, you need `NSMutableDictionary` to change the data. I'm not sure about JSONKit, but the built-in Cocoa JSON parser has a flag to return the data in mutable containers.

In worst case, you can do something like that:

```
NSMutableDictionary* data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[jsonString objectFromJSONString]];
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iRatings] forKey:@"ratings"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// 
// we begin with our string in json format
//
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"{\"1\":\"Hole 1: Rossy Robinson - $25\",\"2\":\"Hole 7: Davey Ambrose - $25\",\"3\":\"Hole 14: Ross Robinson - $25\"}"];

//
// convert the json string to an NSMutableDictionary
//
NSError *e;
NSMutableDictionary *JSONdic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

//
// change a value and add a new value in the dict
//
NSLog(@"before: object for key 1 is: %@", [JSONdic objectForKey:@"1"]);
[JSONdic setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"1"];
[JSONdic setObject:@"Phil McQuitty" forKey:@"2"];

//
//convert dictionary object to json data
//
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONdic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&e];

//
// convert the json data back to a string
//
NSString *jsonText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];\

//
// print out the final results
//
NSLog(@"back to string: %@", jsonText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to change an immutableobject.

```
NSMutableDictionary *deserializedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [jsonString objectFromJSONString]];
```

This is a mutable dictionary and you can change the values in it.

Answer (score 1):

You try like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *deserializedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [jsonString objectFromJSONString]];
```

and then change the values:

```
[deserializedData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iRatings] forKey:@"ratings"];
```

For `NSDictionary` we cannot add or change values, thats why application is crashing.